# Unable to select element with Xpath on website

Tags: xpath

I would like to collect some data from the below website but I am unable to access the elements with Xpath.
I am looking to have people, luggage and gearbox.
I was able to access names of the cars like this `//h3[@class="detailed-car-group__make-model"]`
But all the items in in the following tag are not to be found, you would have to check the link to understand what i mean.

```
//d1[@class="detailed-car-group__info"]
```

[link](https://secure.budget.co.uk/booking?pickupCountry=GB&pickupState=&pickuplocation=Airport&pickupLocations=AIR_BFS_GB&etaDate=16%2F08%2F22&ETAHour=14&pickupMins=00&returnCountry=GB&returnState=&returnlocation=Airport&returnLocations=&ettDate=23%2F08%2F22&ETTHour=14&dropMins=00&discountNumber=&yds-applicable=1&dateOfBirth=&hirefleet=car&sortIndicator=&returnDate=23%2F08%2F22&returnHours=14&returnMins=00)

Comment: `d1`? There's no `d1` in the page.

Comment: @ConalTuohy pls check again, the site was under maintenance